# float, forms, and UL

Tags: html, css-float

I have the following simple html+css code. 
For some reason the second LI item is displayed  kind of centered.
I appreciare if you may test and let me know.
(my post is mostly code, because it is a very simple html page which already shows the issue)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Float</title>
<style>

.el_edit  {
background-image:   url(http://www.w3schools.com/images/compatible_safari.gif);
    background-repeat:  no-repeat;
background-color:   transparent;
    border:         none;
    height:         50px;
    width:          50px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.el_delete  {
background-image: url(http://www.w3schools.com/images/compatible_firefox.gif);
    background-repeat:  no-repeat;
background-color:   transparent;
    border:         none;
    height:         50px;
    width:          50px;
vertical-align:top;
}
</style></head>
<body>
<ul><li>
<div style="float:left;">
<form>
<button class="el_a">A</button>
</form> </div>
<div style="float:right;">
<div style="float:left;">
<form>
<button class="el_edit">B</button>
</form> </div>
<div style="float:right;">
<form>
<button class="el_delete">C</button>
</form></div> 
</div><br>
</li>
<li>
<div style="float:left;">
<form>
<button class="el_a">A1</button>
</form> 
</div>
<div style="float:right;">
<div style="float:left;">
<form>
<button class="el_edit">B1</button>
</form> </div>
<div style="float:right;">
<form>
<button class="el_delete">C1</button>
</form></div> 
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: see how second LI item is kind of centered]
[image: inside-block]
[image: block]
[image: table-row]

Comment: See you on Monday. ps I using Firefox 17.0.1

Comment: What Output u need??? Can u upload the screen shot

Comment: second line should go just below first line, i.e.

Comment: second line should go just below first line, i.e. second line dot just below first line dot, A1 just below A, B1 just below B, C1 just below C (B-C resp. B1-C1 on the far right).

Comment: It seems that it is a margin issue. li {margin: 0 0 50px 0;} helps, where third parameter is as big as button height. Still, there is something about float that I am not able to control.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this CSS may Solve your issue

```
li{display:block}
```

Comment: No, I want second line just below forst line, i.e., second line item dot should go just below first line item dot, and similarly for other elements.

Answer (score 0):

just try following fiddle to check what you want ....

```
<form   name="el">
<button class="el_a">A</button>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WdeAF/

Comment: Which browser you are using...  becouse i tried it on  internet explorer shoed inline...

Comment: Nope. See my edited first img, to see what I wish. Maybe I can't get by float (inside a UL/LI), can I?